# Significance of three days mourning for Gen. Qassim Suleimani

Tags: military, iran

There is a three-day mourning event in Iran over the assassination of Gen. Qassim Suleimani.  Is that a long period of time or a fairly standard period?

In 1989 the Ayatollah Khomeini was mourned for 40 days.

Is there a historical list of national mourning events in Iran to gauge the significance of the duration?

Comment: I think three day and single day are internationally typical values for mourning periods. Btw, this question seems to be far from on-topic.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes? This is a matter of policy, I don't see how it's off topic?

Comment: @yannis may have phrased the question badly but my goal is to understand the significance of 3 days.  For example the former ayatollah Khomeini was mourned for 40 days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misunderstood some things about Iran and mourning. It's standard in Shia Islam to mourn someone for 40 days and to have a big mourning ceremony/gathering on last day of that period. This process was adeptly [exploited](https://books.google.com/books?id=aAfEhkidr8AC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43) during the Iranian revolution, with the deaths of those killed in demonstrations virtually guaranteeing another one after 40 days...

As far as Khomeini's death goes there [were](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZLq5TzLNqkC&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90) 5 days of *national* mourning decreed, this "on top" of the official 40 day period. So yes, the number of national mourning days seems to be an indicator of the importance in the regime of the official that died.

President Rafsanjani [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_state_funeral_of_Akbar_Hashemi_Rafsanjani) also honoured with a 3 day national mourning period, so you could say that  Suleimani got honored on par with an Iranian president, in this respect.